# How to get the facebook app_access_token?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-access-token

I want to create a score for my Facebook app and I know you need an app_access_token for that. Some posts say, the only way to get an app_access_token is via PHP, like this:

```
    <?php

$APPLICATION_ID = YOUR_APP_ID;
$APPLICATION_SECRET = YOUR_APP_SECRET;

$token_url =    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
            "client_id=" . $APPLICATION_ID .
            "&client_secret=" . $APPLICATION_SECRET .
            "&grant_type=client_credentials";
$app_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

?>
```

Is the token you get via this PHP script different from the so called "app token" you find on

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/?

(looks like this: `APPLICATION_ID|lvATVyhp1m.............w`)
and is acually the same you get by calling

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials` directly.

So why must this call be made via PHP?

Comment: The access tokens are the same.  The sites that say that using that PHP script to make the request and retrieve the app access token are incorrect.

Comment: I guess what they meant by 'the only way to get an app_access_token is via PHP' is that you should get it server-side. This is because the request requires your app secret and it should be kept private.

Answer (score 1):

You can get token by various ways

```
<a href='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=2926561407xxxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/fb/getCode.html&rcount=1&scope=email,read_stream'>Login</a>
```

It will return the token through URL you can get it by:

```
function getURLParameters(access_token) 
{
    var sURL = window.document.URL.toString();
    if (sURL.indexOf("?") > 0)
    {
    var arrParams = sURL.split("?"); 
    var arrURLParams = arrParams[1].split("&"); 
    var arrParamNames = new Array(arrURLParams.length);
        var arrParamValues = new Array(arrURLParams.length);     
        var i = 0;

        for (i=0;i<arrURLParams.length;i++)
        {
            var sParam =  arrURLParams[i].split("=");
            arrParamNames[i] = sParam[0];

            if (sParam[1] != "")
              arrParamValues[i] = unescape(sParam[1]);
            else
              arrParamValues[i] = "No Value";
        }

        for (i=0;i<arrURLParams.length;i++)
        {
          if(arrParamNames[i] == "code")
          {
            code = arrParamValues[i];
            return arrParamValues[i];
          }
        }

        return "No Parameters Found";
    }
}
getURLParameters();
```